# Can a person start swimming in the three weeks?

Tags: halacha, minhag, three-weeks

Someone told me that if a person did not swim prior to the three weeks, he may not start swimming during the three weeks? Is there a source for this? (sources)

Comment: What makes you think this is an issue?

Comment: I never heard of it, yet someone told me on Shabbos that there is such a Halacha yet did not know where. I am trying to see if it is accurate or not.

Comment: I think you should probably ask that person for some kind of source since even Google has [never heard of](https://encrypted.google.com/#hl=en&q=%22start+swimming%22+bein+hametzarim&oq=%22start+swimming%22+bein+hametzarim&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=6014l6875l2l7811l2l2l0l0l0l0l231l359l0.1.1l2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2d67a2d90c0f5352&biw=1063&bih=562) such a thing.

Comment: Gershon, please include your "I heard it from someone ..." sourcing in your question. If you're going to ask about halachot whose existence even you aren't sure of, it makes sense to say why you're asking about them. Otherwise, we could have infinite questions like "Are we allowed to eat meat on Wednesdays?"

Comment: Google has heard of it :)  Just not with the phrases you used.  If your custom is not to swim during the three weeks you shouldn't swim, if it is, you can :)

Comment: @avi In that case a stone has heard of it as well, since both basically instantiate inertia.

Comment: I just meant that if you google "swmming" "three weeks" you can find lots of blog posts and other sorts of things of people talking about this custom, and questioning where it comes from.

Comment: What do you mean "start"? Do you mean being a member of a swim team or club? First swim of the summer? Taking lessons?

Comment: Has not swam this year yet, and now wants to start.

Answer (score 2):

Although people say that one may not go swimming for the first time during the Three Weeks, there is no halachic source for this practice. It is therefore not considered a binding custom and it is permitted without Hataras Nedorim (Piskei Teshuvos 551:46).

Comment: That Tshuvah doesn't seem to say anything about swimming for the first time. Is it a different Tshuva, perhaps?: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20026&pgnum=233 (it is a new edition, so maybe he changed things around)

Comment: I saw the above quote on this website (http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?id=8332) and the source quoted was Tshuvos V’Hanhagos 2:263

Answer (score 1):

One may swim during the three weeks, but not after Rosh Chodesh Av.  Some however have a custom not to go swimming during the three weeks at all.

It sounds like those who allow one to "Continue swimming" is a subset of those who don't swim during the 3 weeks, but it is not the normal custom.

http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/TheThreeWeeksBackIssue.pdf

> **Swimming - Three Weeks (not including nine days)**
>
> Some have the custom
>   to refrain from swimming during the three weeks. 121  However,  the
>   custom is to go swimming until  Rosh Chodesh Av. Nonetheless, one
>   should avoid  swimming in dangerous places. 122
>
> 1. Mekor Chaim 551:14:page 289, Orchos Rabbeinu 2:page 129:12. The
>      Steipler zt”l did not change his clothing all  week even during the
>      three weeks except for Shabbos and his tallis kotton (Orchos Rabbeinu
>      2:page 130:17).
> 2. Opinion of Harav Moshe Feinstein zt”l quoted in Moadei Yeshurun
>      page 128:footnote 12, Halichos Shlomo  Moadim 2:14:footnote 7,
>      Teshuvos V’hanhugos 2:263, M’Bais Levi 13:page 22:4:footnote 5 quoting
>      the opinion of  Harav Wosner Shlita, Rivevos Ephraim 3:333, 4:135:14,
>      6:285:2, Shevet Ha’kehusi 1:169:4.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a source for this in the Shulchan Aruch. It's possible this was instated because swimming brings joy, and it isn't appropriate to engage in joyful activities, with a limited number of exceptions, during the 3 weeks. According to the Shulchan Aruch the majority of the stringency's begin on the 1st of Av, notable exceptions being Orach Chaim 551.17 and 551.18. The R'aMA notes in a number of places the custom in Ashkenaz is to be stringent from the 17 of Tammuz (see Orach Chaim Ch. 551.2, 551.4, 551.9). I have not seen the Shulchan Aruch specifically reference swimming.