# May one allow children to play in water on minor fasts?

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, fast-days, swimming

May one allow *children* to play in water on minor fasts? Are the rules the same (depending whom you follow) [as for an adult](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8973/5)?

Comment: CYLOR__________

Answer (score 2):

From the Mishna Brurah [550:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=47) it seems that children who understand what happened on those days  should definitely participate with the tzibbur as much as he can.

Answer (score 2):

The Aruch haShulchan writes (OC 551:31):

> אע"ג דאין אבלות לקטן כמ"ש ביו"ד סי' שפ"ד זהו בסתם אבלות אבל באבלות דרבים שהוא זכרון לחורבן בית קדשינו ראוי לחנך גם הקטנים [מג"א סקל"ח] ולאו משום דאבלות זו חמירא מסתם אבלות דאדרבא שיש דברים שמקילינן באבלות ישנה כדאמרינן ביבמות [מ"ג:] ע"ש אלא דבזה יש חינוך ליראת ד' שהקטן כשישאל על מה זה יבינו לו עניין חורבן בית המקדש
>   Even though [in general] mourning laws do not apply to minors (as outlined in YD 384), this is as regards [personal] mourning; however, for public mourning which is to remember the destruction of our holy Temple, it is proper to educate minors [in this matter]. This is not because the latter form of mourning is more strict, for indeed there are a number of matters in which it is more lenient (as outlined in Yevamot 43b), but rather [doing so] is a way to inculcate fear of God for the minor will inquire what is going on and will come to learn about the destruction of the Temple. (my translation)